# Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first.

Tags: laravel, authentication, reset-password

I Used Laravel Authentication,And in Reset Password I Want to send Reset Link to email.
My .env is here:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=myemail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=MyPassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

And my mail.php:

```
<?php

 return [
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.com'),
'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587);
'from' => [
    'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hanieasemi76@gmail.com'),
    'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'hanie'),
],
'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'ssl'),
'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
'stream' => [
    'ssl' => [
        'allow_self_signed' => true,
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
    ],
],

'markdown' => [
    'theme' => 'default',

    'paths' => [
        resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
    ],
],
];
```

And Turn on 2-step verification of my gmail,But Now When I Want to send email I give this Error `Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. r7-v6sm5414781wrn.83 - gsmtp` 
How I can fixet it?where is my problem?

Comment: Did you change your gmail account settings for sending email ?

Comment: Yes ,I Do  it with app password and 2step verifivation!

Comment: run php artisan config:cache